Which magnetic field is the one in the inductance equation?
Any self induction problem that can be solved via $emf=-N\frac{\Delta \phi}{\Delta t}$ should be equivalently solvable via $-L\frac{\Delta i}{\Delta t}$. What if the coil is already existing in a uniform magnetic field, and the induction is happening because the change of current in the coil while the external field is left unchanged. The inductance is defined through the equation $L=\frac{\phi N}{i}$. My question is does $\phi$ in the last equation include the already existing field? Or just the field due to the current in the coil?

The inductance is defined as $M_{kl} = \Phi_k /I_l$ which is the magnetic flux through loop $k$ due to the magnetic field created by a current $I_l$ in loop $l$. When $k=l$ this is the self-inductance and is conventionally denoted $L_k$. Otherwise, it is the mutual inductance between loops $k$ and $l$. So the flux through loop $k$ is
$$\Phi_k = \sum_l M_{kl} I_l = L_k I_k +\sum_{l| l\neq k}M_{kl}I_l$$
which is the sum of the magnetic field of current in the loop itself and the magnetic fields of the currents in the other loops. So the answer to your question is to simply use the (total) magnetic field. Since your external field does not change with time, it does not contribute to the emf induced in the loop.

The last equation only holds for one isolated coil.
In general, the voltage across the ends of a coil reads
$$v_k = \dot{\psi}_k = N_k \dot{\phi}_k$$
with $\phi_k$, the flux concatenated with the $k^{th}$ coil, is the superposition (= sum) of the fluxes produced by all the coils (or other "sources" of magnetic field), i.e.
$$\phi_k = \sum_j \phi_{kj} = \phi_{kk} + \sum_{j \ne k} \phi_{k j} \ ,$$
and each contribution can be written as a function of the magnetic resistance $\theta_{kj}$ and magnetic field generation $m_j = N_j i_j$ so that:

the dispersed flux magnetic circuit reads:
$$m_k := N_k i_k = \phi_{kk} \theta_{kk} \quad \rightarrow \quad \phi_{kk} = \frac{N_k}{\theta_{kk}} i_k$$
the magnetic circuit of a flux concatenated with 2 coils reads:
$$m_k + m_i = \phi_{kj} \theta_{kj} \quad \rightarrow \quad 
\phi_{kj} = \frac{N_k}{\theta_{kj}} i_k +  \frac{N_j}{\theta_{kj}} i_j $$

and the overall flux through the $k^{th}$ coil can be expressed as a function of the electric currents in the coil as
$$\begin{aligned}
\psi_k = N_k \phi_k & = N_k \phi_{kk} + N_k  \sum_{j \ne k} \phi_{k j} = \\
& = N_k \frac{N_k}{\theta_{kk}} i_k + N_k \sum_{j \ne k} \left( \frac{N_k}{\theta_{kj}} i_k +  \frac{N_j}{\theta_{kj}} i_j \right) = \\
& = N_k^2 \sum_{j} \frac{1}{\theta_{kj}} i_k + \sum_{j \ne k} \frac{N_k N_j}{\theta_{kj}} i_j = \\
& = L_k i_k + \sum_{j \ne k} M_{kj} i_j \ ,
 \end{aligned}$$
being $L_k = N_k^2 \sum_{j} \frac{1}{\theta_{kj}}$ the self-inductance and $M_{kj} = \frac{N_k N_j}{\theta_{kj}}$ the mutual inductance of coils $j$ and $k$.
